# How to find centerX and centerY for the Arc

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I have the two Angle(a1, a2) to draw the Arc and it's positions are (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) respectively. Using this information, I want to find the center position of Arc and need to draw the arc. I don't know the radius of circle.

Please refer my attachment to understand the requirement. The first Arc position (x1, y1) is always constant.

[image]

Second angle will be changed dynamically. So when you changing second angle, the Radius and centerX, centerY value of circle changed.

Anyone help me, how to find the Radius of this Imagine Circle. If you need anymore information let me know.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: You cannot determine a circle (and thus its centre and radius) from just a chord, since there are an infinite number of circles for any given chord.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: but two angles are also given, so in general there is no possible circle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the angles are the bearings of the points from the (unknown) centre then the line from (x1,y1) with direction Angle1+180 and the line from (x2,y2) with direction Angle2+180 will intersect at the centre, so you find the centre by computing the intersection point of these two lines. The radius will then be the distance of either point from the centre.

Comment: How to find intersection point of these two lines..? is there any formula.?

Comment: If you know vectors and trig at all I'd say yes.